Angular 17 SSR + ISR Pages got de-indexed and not indexing
I have recently built an SSR application using angular 17 and ISR from rx-angular/isr.
Initially, Everything was going fine, Pages were getting indexed properly. But after 13 August 2024, My pages started getting de-indexed without any changes. I know Google released core changes on 14-15 August I guess.
My Sitemap, Robots.txt, Meta, and tags are correct. Please check the attached code. I have replaced the original domain with a dummy domain.
Please check if I am missing something.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Site</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5">
  <meta name="description" content="Site Description">
  <meta name="author" content="Site">

  <meta property="og:title" content="Site | Some Page title">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Site Description">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/page">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://images.site.co/common/meta.png">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="example.com">

  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Site | Some Page title">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="Site Description">
  <meta name="twitter:url" content="https://example.com/page">


  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="@site_name">
  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@site_name">
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://images.site.co/common/meta.png">

  <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/page">
  
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

Here's robots.txt file
User-agent: *

Allow: /

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap-main.xml
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap-page1.xml
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap-page2.xml
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap-page3.xml
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap-page4.xml
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap-page5.xml
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap-page6.xml

Sample sitemap.xml file
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>https://example.com/sitemap-main.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2024-09-11T11:07:17.068Z</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>https://example.com/sitemap-page1.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2024-09-11T11:07:17.068Z</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>https://example.com/sitemap-page2.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2024-09-11T11:07:17.068Z</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>https://example.com/sitemap-page3.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2024-09-11T11:07:17.068Z</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>https://example.com/sitemap-page4.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2024-09-11T11:07:17.068Z</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>https://example.com/sitemap-page5.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2024-09-11T11:07:17.068Z</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>https://example.com/sitemap-page6.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2024-09-11T11:07:17.068Z</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>

Here's the Lighthouse report

As you can see SEO is 100 for every page.
Still, my pages got de-indexed and are not indexing anymore.
Am I missing something? Also, let me know if this is not the right platform for these questions. I Raised the query to the Google support forum but as expected from them, they don't have a clue about it.
Below is how it started getting de-indexed.

I really appreciate any help you can provide. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.
